# Android: can a module depend on another module?

Tags: android, android-studio, module, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following case:

The MainApp depends upon ModuleA
But then ModuleA depends upon ModuleB. ModuleA is mine, but ModuleB is AAR file, from third party so I can't change it.

When I compile my ModuleA as AAR, and then in a new project called 'Another game', import both these modules, and setup the same structure, i.e. main app dependent on ModuleA and then set up ModuleA on ModuleB, it fails. Here is the build.gradle of ModuleA and the errors. Any idea how what I am doing wrong here?

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default") 
artifacts.add("default", file('moduleA.aar'))
dependencies {
    compile project(':moduleB')
}
```

[image]

Comment: the aar you made is based on gradle file system ?

Comment: yes it is gradle based